How to get the total salary of an employee in OCL?
In the standard of OCL, https://www.omg.org/spec/OCL/2.4/PDF p. 7, an UML class diagram defines a class association between a Person and a Company called Job with a salary attribute. Cardinality is multiple on both sides (0..*).
As I understand, an instance of Person can have multiple jobs. In order to access these jobs, OCL create automatically an "navigation" attribute called "job". My questions are :
The expression, self.job, where self is an instance of Person or Company, is for me a collection of instances of Job.
In order to get the income of a Person p, the sum of all its salaries, I should do :
p.job->collect(j : Job | j.salary)->sum()
But, the standard writes:
p. 10 : job.salary -- income from regular job
It seems the standard considers only one job for a Person.
p. 12 : def: income : Integer = self.job.salary->sum()
I can't understand this. Is job a single instance? If yes why applying sum() on only one salary?
And later :
p. 27 : (where c is a Company)
wellpaidEmployees: Set(Person) = c.Job->select(salary>10000).employee->asSet(),
totalSalary: Integer = c.Job.salary->sum()

Here, c.Job (with a capital J) is a collection on first line (using -> and select).
On the second line, Job is now a single object with "." (as I understand, -> is applied on collection, . is applied on single object).
I don't really understand how it works and I'm a little lost. Is self.job.salary the collection of all the salaries of all the jobs ?
A lot of examples on the Internet are extracted from the standard. The standard has been reviewed by many smart people so I must miss something somewhere...
I asked ChatGPT about that, here is my prompt and its anwser below. To my surprise, it thinks like me (even if it merges Company and Job):
I have an UML diagram. There are two classes: Person and Company.
A person works in one or more company for a salary.
How can I get the sum of its salaries in OCL ?

Answer:
To calculate the sum of salaries for a Person working in one or more Company classes using Object Constraint Language (OCL), you can define an OCL expression that iterates over the collection of companies the person works for and sums the salaries.
Given the following UML diagram:
    Person class
        Attributes: name: String
        Associations: worksFor: Company[1..*] (A person works for one or more companies)

    Company class
        Attributes: name: String, salary: Integer

The OCL expression to calculate the sum of salaries for a Person would look like this:
context Person
inv: totalSalary : Integer = self.worksFor->collect(salary)->sum()

Explanation:
`self.worksFor` retrieves the collection of Company instances associated with the Person.
`collect(salary)` extracts the salary attribute from each Company.
`sum()` calculates the sum of all salaries in the collection.

This expression assumes that salary is an attribute of the Company and that the salary is defined as an Integer. The result is the total salary of the Person across all companies they work for.

I found the answer in The Object Constraint Language Second Edition, Jos Warmer and Anneke Kleppe, Addison-Wesley, 2003:
This the "collect shorthand" described in pages 31, 69 (3.10.5) and 152 (9.3.11) :
partners.numberOfCustomers ⇔ partners->collect(numberOfCustomers)

So job.salary->sum() is equivalent to job.collect(salary)->sum().
And I would even extend it as:
job.collect(j : Job | j.salary)->sum()
